# Why does the action of $S_3$ representation not equal to the direct sum of its irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

This might be a really simple question..

The representation $(\rho,\mathbb C^3)$ of $S_3$ can be decomposed to $(\rho_1\oplus \rho_3,W\oplus W')$, where $W=\{k(1,1,1)|k\in \mathbb C\}$, $W'=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)|x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}$,
$\rho_1(\sigma)=1\forall \sigma \in S_3$ and $\rho_3$ is the standard representation depicted in the following link: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation_of_symmetric_group:S3.

So, for instance, why is it that $\rho(123)(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_3,x_1,x_2)\neq (x_1,-x_3,x_2-x_3)=(\rho_1\oplus \rho_3)(123)(x_1,x_2,x_3)$?

Comment: Try to write down exactly what the maps $\rho_1$ and $\rho_3$ are. What is $\rho_1 \oplus \rho_3$? It doesn't make immediate sense to me.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: The direct sums in your example are not the same. In the first, you are talking about $W$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$, for example $(1, 1, 1)$ is a vector in $W$. When you later try to apply $\rho_1 \oplus \rho_3$, you are thinking that $W = \mathbb{C}$, so for example $(1)$ is a vector in $W$. These isomorphic representations, but not equal.

Comment: I agree it's not rigorous. Can you show me how to decompose it correctly? How to make my example work?

Comment: Try to do what I suggested in my first comment: try to write down what you mean by $\rho_1$ in the context of $W$.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it.. If I decompose an element of $\mathbb C^3$ to a sum of elements of $W,W'$, and act with the corresponding action, I get the equality I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Let $u=(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3$. Then
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(u,u,u)+(x_1-u,x_2-u,x_3-u)$$ with the first summand from $W$ and the latter from $W'$. Then 
$$\rho(123)(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(u,u,u)+(x_3-u,x_1-u,x_2-u)$$ and the problem hopefully disappears.